# how i can make windows server 2003 see some directory from UNIX-AIX?

Tags: windows-server-2003, unix, command-line-interface, file-sharing, aix

how i can make windows server 2003 see some directory from UNIX-AIX

Comment: share files between windows server 2003 and unix aix 6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share it out with NFS then [*configure*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324055) [Windows Services for UNIX](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778)

Other alternative is to configure Samba on AIX & share it out that way.

Comment: i want to ask you ... i have AIX 6.1 ... this version contain samba built in or i must download it to AIX if yes how i can download it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Samba on your AIX system then [**this**](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/aix/enewsletterexclusive/24006p1.aspx) article will give you information on how to install it from the expansion pack. Once you've got Samba working you can share the directory from AIX and mount it as a network drive on the Windows 2003 server.